# How to apply function to multiple sheets when loading by IDs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

each day I run a script to format the appearance of a dozen or so new spreadsheets that are automatically generated.

First I place them in a folder on Google drive and run a script that generates a list of all file ID's in the folder, then I copy and paste each ID into a new script 1 at a time and run it.
Basically I am loading the sheets by using `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<id goes here>");`

Since I already have the list of 15 or so ID's (this number can change each day), I'm wondering if there's a way I can alter the script so that it will go through each ID and complete. Here's an example of what the code would be:

```
function format() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<id goes here>");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  for(var i=2; i<=numRows; i++){
    sheet.setRowHeight(i, 320);
    }
  sheet.deleteColumn(3);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 72);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 150);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 300);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(4, 150);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(5, 150);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(6, 300);
  var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  if (maxColumns-lastColumn != 0){
      sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn+1, maxColumns-lastColumn);
      }
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  if (maxRows-numRows != 0){
      sheet.deleteRows(numRows+1, maxRows-numRows);
    } 
};
```

Comment: I was able to do this by listing the contents of the folder and putting my original script in a while statement that used openByID on the file ID variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ex:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('<folder ID goes here>');
var contents = folder.getFiles();
var file;
var name;
var id;
while(contents.hasNext()) {
file = contents.next();
name = file.getName();
id = file.getId()
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);

and continue on from here
```